# Unbounded Knapsack to minimize the total value

Tags: dynamic

I am trying to find a solution to the minimum knapsack problem (least profitable set of items such that the total weight of the selected items is at least the capacity C.)

I am trying to modify the following maximum knapsack problem to get the min version without success.

Could anyone help to solve this problem?

```
public class UnboundedKnapSack {
public static int fillTable(int capacity, int[] weight, int[] value) {
    int i, j;
    int[][] maxValue = new int[value.length][capacity + 1];

    for (j = 0; j < weight[0]; j++) {
        maxValue[0][j] = 0;
    }
    for (j = 0; j <= capacity; j++) {
        maxValue[0][j] = value[0] * (j / weight[0]);
    }

    for (i = 1; i < value.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < weight[i]; j++) {
            maxValue[i][j] = maxValue[i - 1][j];
        }
        for (j = weight[i]; j <= capacity; j++) {
            maxValue[i][j] = Math.max(maxValue[i - 1][j], value[i] + maxValue[i][j - weight[i]]);
        }
    }
    return maxValue[value.length - 1][capacity];
}   
}
```

Comment: Why don't you show us what you have done so far and clarify the specific issue you are having?

Comment: My main problem is to reformulate the recursion if ( capacity == 0 then min[i][j] = 0) and (min[i][j] == infinity if i=0 and j>0)